# Macbook Pro 2010 Late Kernel Panic issues

Tags: macos, crash, graphics, kernel-panic

I've had random kernel panics on my computer since about the time I updated to OSX Yosemite. I should add that I have a crucial m500 SSD and use the mini port to connect my laptop to a large external monitor which may be causing part of this.

I probably had 5 kernel panics throughout my day (I work all day on my laptop) and noticed that this often happened after I had been away from my laptop and it was in sleep mode or when I used google drive spreadsheets and typed in any information.

I turned off sleep mode on the computer and stopped using the external monitor + google drive and now it seems to happen randomly about twice per day. It's so frustrating! Please see panic below - appears it is graphics related. Any help is greatly appreciated. Also I ran apple hardware test and nothing was wrong. Will reset PRAM to rule that out in a second:

Anonymous UUID:       C80F6F64-F6A2-AB5C-5518-1FFBFFD11150

Mon Mar 16 13:56:27 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff7f8c1aaf63): "GPU Panic: [] 3 3 7f 0 0 0 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff80b184a000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P2/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.8.6/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80a06c2ca0 : 0xffffff800952fe41 
0xffffff80a06c2d20 : 0xffffff7f8c1aaf63 
0xffffff80a06c2e00 : 0xffffff7f8a0c2b9f 
0xffffff80a06c2ec0 : 0xffffff7f8a18c18e 
0xffffff80a06c2f00 : 0xffffff7f8a18c1fe 
0xffffff80a06c2f70 : 0xffffff7f8a40b056 
0xffffff80a06c30a0 : 0xffffff7f8a1af82d 
0xffffff80a06c30c0 : 0xffffff7f8a0c95f1 
0xffffff80a06c3170 : 0xffffff7f8a0c70fc 
0xffffff80a06c3370 : 0xffffff7f8a0c8a4b 
0xffffff80a06c3440 : 0xffffff7f8b74e7aa 
0xffffff80a06c3520 : 0xffffff7f8b74ba7c 
0xffffff80a06c35a0 : 0xffffff7f8b74c631 
0xffffff80a06c3620 : 0xffffff7f8b74ce56 
0xffffff80a06c3760 : 0xffffff7f8b74d8fb 
0xffffff80a06c3890 : 0xffffff7f8b780bce 
0xffffff80a06c38d0 : 0xffffff7f8b781923 
0xffffff80a06c3910 : 0xffffff7f8b77b34c 
0xffffff80a06c3a70 : 0xffffff7f8b77bc5c 
0xffffff80a06c3ab0 : 0xffffff7f8b777213 
0xffffff80a06c3ae0 : 0xffffff7f8b75a3a4 
0xffffff80a06c3b30 : 0xffffff8009b00652 
0xffffff80a06c3b60 : 0xffffff8009b01249 
0xffffff80a06c3bc0 : 0xffffff8009afe9c3 
0xffffff80a06c3d00 : 0xffffff80095e4a87 
0xffffff80a06c3e10 : 0xffffff8009533f8c 
0xffffff80a06c3e40 : 0xffffff8009518a93 
0xffffff80a06c3e90 : 0xffffff80095293bd 
0xffffff80a06c3f10 : 0xffffff80096059fa 
0xffffff80a06c3fb0 : 0xffffff8009636ea6 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f8a072000->0xffffff7f8a2dbfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[56AD16B5-4F29-3F74-93E7-D492B3966DE2]@0xffffff7f89d24000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[E5A48E71-70F5-3B01-81D3-C2B037BBE80A]@0xffffff7f8a062000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[619F6C9F-0461-3BA1-A75F-53BB0F87ACD3]@0xffffff7f8a01b000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla(10.0)[7FE40648-F15F-3E18-91E2-FDDDF4CDA355]@0xffffff7f8a2e6000->0xffffff7f8a58ffff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f8a072000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[56AD16B5-4F29-3F74-93E7-D492B3966DE2]@0xffffff7f89d24000
         com.apple.GeForceTesla(10.0)[3EA67900-B4A9-30BB-964D-0904DA5421CC]@0xffffff7f8b71d000->0xffffff7f8b7eafff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[56AD16B5-4F29-3F74-93E7-D492B3966DE2]@0xffffff7f89d24000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[E5A48E71-70F5-3B01-81D3-C2B037BBE80A]@0xffffff7f8a062000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[619F6C9F-0461-3BA1-A75F-53BB0F87ACD3]@0xffffff7f8a01b000
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.0)[796AE430-39FB-3255-8161-D52AFA28EE2B]@0xffffff7f8a072000
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.8.6)[BE610379-FAEA-3E8F-B6AF-F92B70B3C5CD]@0xffffff7f8c19c000->0xffffff7f8c1affff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.8.6)[76B001B1-30F1-3D72-B264-85D77B254C2F]@0xffffff7f8c194000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[70E2B65E-A91A-3522-A1A0-79FD63EABB4C]@0xffffff7f89fa9000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[56AD16B5-4F29-3F74-93E7-D492B3966DE2]@0xffffff7f89d24000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[619F6C9F-0461-3BA1-A75F-53BB0F87ACD3]@0xffffff7f8a01b000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.1.0)[42706EB3-1447-3931-A668-FBAC58AAAA7A]@0xffffff7f8c197000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
14C1510

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.1.0: Thu Feb 26 19:26:47 PST 2015; root:xnu-2782.10.73~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 270413F7-3B44-3602-894F-AC0D392FCF8E
Kernel slide:     0x0000000009200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8009400000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8009300000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 34528340412373
last loaded kext at 3624603954578: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs  3.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f8c31a000, size 389120)
last unloaded kext at 1063315140933: com.parallels.kext.hypervisor  10.1.4 28883 (addr 0xffffff7f8c2ae000, size 319488)
loaded kexts:
com.parallels.virtualsound  1.0.36 36
com.squirrels.airparrot.framebuffer 3
com.squirrels.driver.AirParrotSpeakers  1.7
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 11.0
com.apple.nke.asp-tcp   8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.15.5
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   269.25
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   269.25
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.8.6
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 10.0.0
com.apple.GeForceTesla  10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.3
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.8.6
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 269.25
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.8.6
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.2f6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 269.25
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 269.25
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   10.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.8.1d38
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.10.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   710.55
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 710.4.14
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 396
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1

Comment: you are right, it is graphics related. could you disable "parallels" and the squirrels.driver.AirParrotSpeakers

Comment: How do I disable these? I can uninstall... somewhere in system settings?

Comment: 2 ways click/hold alt+cmd+esc and in the new pop up window shut them down. If they are not there open Activity monitor find them and quit them there.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to read up on the general case and then report back with an edit once you have several crashes and can compare one to the other:

- General advice on troubleshooting kernel panics is here: [What is a Kernel Panic and what does it mean?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199737/what-is-a-kernel-panic-and-what-does-it-mean)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem from Apple. I made a program to fix this issue. You can check it out here, it's free and open-source : https://github.com/julian-poidevin/MBPMid2010_GPUFix/